# Using React to make a simple messaging board. Do I have to set up a server, or can I store state locally?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm new to React and am working on my first React project (that isn't a tutorial or online class assignment). I'm making a simple message board where I'm loading 'threads' (think threads as in posts on Reddit) and comments on those threads via a JSON file I made. The comments correspond to posts based on ID and parent ID key:value pairs in each JSON object.

The functionality I want to add is the ability to comment on any comment (or the parent thread). I've been researching and it seems like doing things like a POST-type request would require setting up a server. But what if I want to just update the JSON locally? In other words, when I submit a comment on my app, it gets stored in the local JSON object so it remains there.

From everything I've read about similar projects with React, people use Redux or Firebase or something to handle requests. This is just a small project to get my feet wet, and I'm not trying to make the app fully operational - it's just a front end self-challenge. Forgive the naivety - maybe I just don't yet fully grasp the concept of state in React, or perhaps I'm not thinking of the right thing here.

I don't need to set up a server to do this, right? I would think I could just have a component that updates the state, which is the JSON?

I'm still in the process of building the actual app - I'd like to get this figured out in case I do need to configure some sort of server or request handling.

The JSON looks like this:

```
"users"​: 
[
{​"id"​:​ ​"1"​, ​"name"​:​ ​"Alice"​}, {​"id"​:​ ​"2"​, ​"name"​:​ ​"Bob"​}, {​"id"​:​ ​"3"​, ​"name"​:​ ​"Carol"​}
], 
"comments"​: 
[
{​"id"​:​ ​"1"​, ​"author"​:​ ​"1"​, ​"subject"​:​ ​"subject of post/thread one"​, ​"body"​: "body of the post here"​, ​"parent"​:​ ​null​},

{​"id"​:​ ​"2"​, ​"author"​:​ ​"2"​, ​"subject"​:​ ​"a comment on post/thread one"​, ​"body"​:​ ​""​, ​"parent"​:​ ​"1"​},

{​"id"​:​ ​"3"​, ​"author"​:​ ​"1"​, ​"subject"​:​ ​""​, ​"body"​:​ ​"a comment on id 2's comment"​, "parent"​:​ ​"2"​},

{​"id"​:​ ​"4"​, ​"author"​:​ ​"3"​, ​"subject"​:​ ​"subject of second post/thread here"​, ​"body"​:​ ​"body of the second post here"​, ​"parent"​:​ ​null​},

{​"id"​:​ ​"5"​, ​"author"​:​ ​"2"​, ​"subject"​:​ ​"comment on id 3's comment"​, ​"parent"​:​ ​"3"​},

{​"id"​:​ ​"6"​, ​"author"​:​ ​"1"​, ​"subject"​:​ ​"a post/thread on id 4's thread"​, ​"body"​:​ ​"body of child post/thread"​, ​"parent"​:​ ​"4"​},

{​"id"​:​ ​"7"​, ​"author"​:​ ​"3"​, ​"subject"​:​ ​""​, ​"body"​:​ ​"another comment on id 2's comment"​, "parent"​:​"2"​}
],

​"favoriteComments"​: [​"1"​] }
```

I'm hoping to be able to update the JSON with new comments so the page maintains the state, but do I have to configure a server/back end for this? Couldn't I just manipulate the JSON by pushing new comments into it?

Second is favoriting comments. I'd probably just use an event here and push into the favorites array. I don't need to keep track of favorites - it'd just be a boolean on each thread set to either true/false IF I have any favorite comments in said thread.

Other points: I don't want to be able to create new threads - saving that for later. Also, the app assumes the user is logged in, so authentication and users are mocked for now.

Comment: Sure, you can just manipulate the local data without any backend, but that would only change the data for the user who's doing it so it's generally not enough for most apps. But if it's enough for you then go for it.

Comment: @JJJ Okay, cool! Yeah, I'm making this as a sort of 'simulation' and to learn, so I'm not worried about actually pushing this into production. Thanks for the clarification - I was just a bit confused because so many tutorials/projects talk about using servers. 'ppreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this client side without a back-end.

For instance, you can store the above data in a component such as ReactTable.

```
<ReactTable>
   data = {data}
   columns: [
      {
       Header : "Header",
       columns: [
          {
            Header:    "Author",
            id:        "author",
            accessor => d.comments.author
          },
          {
            Header:   "Subject",
            id:       "subject",
            accessor => d.comments.subject
         },
       ]
    }
  ]
/>
```

This will store the JSON and render in ReactTable component, which you can view client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try out in [In-memory JavaScript Datastore with Persistence](http://lokijs.org/#/)